# What is the purpose of queueCount inside VkDeviceQueueCreateInfo?

Tags: vulkan

https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0/man/html/VkDeviceQueueCreateInfo.html

What I currently do:

Find a device that has a queue that supports graphics and surface.

I then find the index for the `graphicsQueue` and the `surfaceQueue`. In my case they are the same, but I think they can be different as well.

Now I have always set `queueCount` to be 1 and I didn't run into any problems so far, but I probably should set to the `queueCount` to `VkQueueFamilyProperties.queueCount`.

But now I am wondering what it actually does? Does a higher `queueCount` indicate better performance?

Comment: @NicolBolas I just made a mistake, I set queueCount correctly to 1, but I confused it with the flags parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's how many queues of that family you want to use. A queue family is a group of queues that can all do the same things.

Setting `queueCount` to 0 is not allowed:

> [Valid usage [of VkDeviceQueueCreateInfo]](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0-wsi_extensions/xhtml/vkspec.html#VkDeviceQueueCreateInfo)
>
> - queueCount must be greater than 0

That you got a functioning queue from vkGetDeviceQueue of that family after that is a result of undefined behavior. It could have just as well crashed your program.

> [Valid usage [of vkGetDeviceQueue]](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0-wsi_extensions/xhtml/vkspec.html#VkDeviceQueueCreateInfo)
>
> - queueIndex must be less than the number of queues created for the specified queue family index when device was created, *via the queueCount member of the VkDeviceQueueCreateInfo structure*

Answer (score 1):

No, this has nothing to do with performance. QueueCount (for queue creation) is the number of queues you want to create with that call for the selected queue family index.

So if you e.g. want to create 4 compute queues you can create them all at once with one single call to vkGetDeviceQueue by selecting a (queue) family index that supports compute and setting queueCount to 4. An example of a device that offers multiple queue families [can be found here](http://vulkan.gpuinfo.org/displayreport.php?id=440#queuefamilies).

Comment: "*An example of a device that offers multiple queue families can be found here.*" Multiple queue families has nothing to do with multiple queue objects of the *same* family. Which is what `queueCount` covers.

Comment: This answer confuses me. I don't see how it's possible to retrieve 4 queue handles with a single call to `vkGetDeviceQueue`, since doc for that function says: "pQueue is a pointer to a VkQueue object that will be filled with the handle for the requested queue".
What I think you meant is that we can ask for, e.g., 4 compute queues by specifying `VkDeviceQueueCreateInfo::queueCount` to be 4, and then later call `vkGetDeviceQueue` 4 times to retrieve each queue created.
Am I wrong?